# Calling methods

Tags: java, methods, actionlistener

Okay below is code by which a `JOptionPane` message will appear if table number and waiter name text fields have no information in them, it is in a two part question, the first part is in the code below the part of the question I want answered is:

> "Otherwise, call the calculateSubtotal method, which you implement in the next step, to calculate the subtotal of the bill. The calculateSubtotal method takes no arguments and returns a double containing the subtotal, which you should display in subtotalJTextField. Calculate and display the tax and the total of the bill in JTextFields taxJTextField and totalJTextField, respectively. The tax rate is specified in a constant TAX_RATE."

```
private void calculateBillJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event ){
    String tableNumber = tableNumberJTextField.getText().trim();
    String waiterName = waiterNameJTextField.getText().trim();
    if (tableNumber.length() == 0 || waiterName.length() == 0){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Information in Table Number and Waiter Name "
                + "must be entered");
    } else {
    }
}
```

The method to the question I want answered is below:

```
private double calculateSubtotal(){
    return 0;
} // end method calculateSubtotal
```

If the fields have no information in them how do I call the `Subtotal` method within 
`calculateBillJButtonActionPerformed`?

Comment: Smells like homework to me, anyways you need to call the function in the else statement, there's no need for calling it if there's no information because you have already submitted an error message and it's up to the user to do it again

Comment: Its a bloody assignment that's doing my head in :) What is the Call function code for the ELSE statement? im not sure of how to write the code.

Comment: @Poldie, i had to put the whole question in, it looks like two questions but they are related, i already did the first bit, unsure of the rest.

Comment: Have you read your question? It's really lacking clarity. Are you asking how to call a method? Then the answer is: `caculateSubtotal()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can put value of calculateSubtotal() in another variable of course..

```
  if (tableNumber.length() == 0 || waiterName.length() == 0){
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Information in Table Number and Waiter Name "
            + "must be entered");
  } else {
double total = calculateSubtotal(); 
String s = "" + total;
subtotalJTextField.setText(s);
double tax = total / TAX_RATE;
String s1 = "" + tax;
taxJTextField.setText(s1);  }  }
```

Not make TAX_RATE constant and do your calculations in calculateSubtotal() and you are done.